# Serverless v3 Conditions

Tags: conditional-statements, serverless

We were using Serverless Framework Version 2. Now we're switching it to the version 3. Everything works as is except for the Conditions. They're just ignored and all the resources are trying to be created on all the environments.

Yaml code sample:

```yaml
service: service-name
frameworkVersion: '3' # was '2' before

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: provided
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  # some other configs here...

resources:
  Conditions:
    CreateProdResources: !Equals
      - ${self:provider.stage}
      - prod
  Resources:
    SqsQueueName:
      Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
      Condition: CreateProdResources
      Properties:
        # Some SQS properties here
```

When I switch it over to Serverless v3, my IDE starts complaining on the line: `Condition: CreateProdResources`, saying "Schema validation: Property 'Condition' is not allowed".

Tried to find anything here: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/guides/upgrading-v3 - no luck. Google seems also "not aware" of the issue.

Any suggestion please?